# blackberry RAPC exception occurred

Tags: blackberry, cordova

```
 [exec] I/O Error: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, T
```

he system cannot find the file specified
     [exec] [ERROR]                     RAPC exception occurred

Comment: Similar to question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541630/blackberry-error-cannot-run-program-jar-createprocess-error-2-the-system-ca/17565581#17565581
Please see the answer posted in this link.

Answer (score -1):

You MUST use the default setting when installing the SDK at:

/Developer/SDKs/Research In Motion/BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.5

Comment: That's a UNIX/OSX path, and it looks like they're using Windows.